# Does PhD GPA matter after grad school regarding academic funding?

Tags: funding, grades, gpa

There are many similar questions regarding whether PhD GPA matters after grad school, but this question is specific to obtaining academic funding as a professor. When applying for funding, do funding agencies look at the professors previous GPA and take that into consideration?

Comment: The concept of a PhD GPA doesn't even exist in most countries.

Answer (score 10):

It is extremely unlikely that anyone would care, especially a source of funds. They are interested in you research potential and your productivity. There might be various aspects to that for specialized awards, but no one will ask you for your doctoral level transcripts. They are largely meaningless in any case.

If you passed comprehensive exams then you learned enough to go forward and that is assumed if you completed a doctorate.

Answer (score 0):

Unless your transcript is part of your application package, a review panel for funding would have no access to such information.  The only way they could find out would be if a member of the review panel taught you, and if that occurred, that member would probably have to declare themselves in conflict.  In the US, that means they wouldn't even be able to be in the room while your application is discussed.